# What would happen to a block of warm ice (made out of pure pressure) once the pressure is gone?

Tags: science-based, physics, chemistry, ice

Imaginary situation where you could exert 10GPA worth of pressure on a floating cubic meter chunk of water. According to this [**graph**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hn5mM.png), it'd turn into ice even if it's still around the room's temperature(say, 30c~).

My question then is what'd happen to this block of ice once the pressure is gone back to normal earth pressure: Will it melt immediately? Will its temperature remain the same 30c while/if it's melting? etc

Comment: unless you have a press with water under it at 10 GPa which is going to fail soon, it'd be better to wait 24 before accepting an answer. In this way you allow more users to drop in and give their contribution. Worldbuilding problems can.

Comment: Amit, it is usual to wait about 24 hours before accepting an answer to give people from all timezones a chance to formulate an answer. Accepting my answer now discourages people from making more answers, and someone might come up with a better and more detailed explanation than mine! That would be a waste to miss.

Comment: What is the worldbuilding problem or issue specific to your own invented world that you're trying to solve? This is a straight up Real World Science question, which really doesn't belong here without meaningful context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a comment that doesnt fit.

It is a solid because it is compressed this far. It also does not compress any further because it is exerting an equal force of 10GPA back. So if you release the pressure it will expand at the same rate you release it. Instantaneously remove the 10GPA? The ice will move outwards at 10GPA pressure as it expands, turns to solid and then to gass due to the energy it receives as it expands outwards. Remove the pressure slowly? It'll expand at that slow rate. The expansion would likely not be much. Water is notoriously hard to compress, so the particles might push outwards at 10GPA they would likely only move a few centimeters at most before they reach their uncompressed 1 atmosphere state. As L.Dutch said, it wouldnt be an explosion.

One potential caveat that MIGHT be true for water: if it is compressed its energy density will increase along with its density meaning it effectively heats up. If you allow the material to reach room temperature before you release it, it'll expand and suddenly be able to carry much more energy (similar to a can of air that gets cold when you release its pressure, but this is apparently not true for everything). That would mean that it would be extremely cold after expansion and turn into cracked ice splinters that suck energy out of their surroundings. But I'm not sure about that.

Comment: The reason why liquid are safer than gases in pressurized circuit is that, due to their extremely high compressibility ratio, a leak is sufficient to remove all the pressure, while gases would cause an explosion. Therefore I am not sure depressurizing here would cause an explosion as you state.

Comment: @L.Dutch true, most gasses expands a few thousand times while especially water would likely just expand a small amount despite the pressure. I'll change it.

Comment: @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica yes, the density of solid and liquids does not change to the degree that gases do under pressure, the energy density of the water H2O would still increase as Demigan states. If rapidly decompressing from liquid state at say 1 Gpa at 50 C to atmospheric pressure, the energy change in the water cannot be expressed as work done through a volume change (which would necessitate a density change), instead by the first law of thermodynamics the water would first rapidly heat which would turn it into a gas and then rapidly expand, creating an explosion

Answer (score 1):

Once the pressure was released the ice would no longer to stable. Cubic ice VII has a density in excess of 1.65 g/cc at the temperature and pressure that you specify and if the pressure were suddenly released the ice would expand immediately and explosively to a density something around 0.92 g/cc of regular ice. Such an abrupt change in structure and density would totally shatter the block of ice into tiny crystals of ordinary ice for an instant before these melted into liquid water. The result would be a very wet explosion.